# How to change sequelize property name after join

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have an issue in sequelize orm. The data return after join has an object nested:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "duongdoican@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$12$OQHHb/D9JAs6tyclVzPWMeSVkbcR2tSmmMq9VHaqnWm3C/UKPYyNm",
    "role": {
        "name": "admin"
    }
}
```

I expect the result to be:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "duongdoican@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$12$OQHHb/D9JAs6tyclVzPWMeSVkbcR2tSmmMq9VHaqnWm3C/UKPYyNm",
    "role": "admin"
}
```

Because I join only 1 field from role table to user table so I want to change name like that, but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```js
User.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: Role,
            attributes: ["name"],
            required: true
          },
        ],
        plain: true,
      });
```

});

Someone help me, please!

Comment: Please show the formatted text blocks instead of links with screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following as an alias:

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: ["id", "username", "password", [Sequelize.col("roles.name"), "role"]],
  include: [
    {
      model: Role,
      as: 'roles', // alias, define in your model (if not defined)
      attributes: [],
      required: true
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Correct this is when alias is defined in  model

Comment: If it has solved your problem, then accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: ["id", "username", "password", "Role.name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: Role,
      attributes: [],
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  plain: true,
});
```